# Getting "segmentation fault" after the execution of whole code

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

i am getting segementation fault after the execution of all my C code. It generates the rquired output with zero byte memory leak. After that, it shows "segmentation fault".Following is the  `gdb`  output.

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x08060f90 in _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ ()
(gdb) bt 
#0  0x08060f90 in _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ ()
#1  0xffbecd18 in ?? ()  
#2  0x15048815 in ?? ()
#3  0xcd0fbecd in ?? ()
#4  0x0610ffbe in ?? () 
#5  0xffbecd08 in ?? ()
#6  0xf7f79ff4 in ?? () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

EDIT

```
    char **Connections,**Doors,**Zones;
    char *s1,*s2;
    char con[] = "c_";
    char zon[] = "z_";
    char dor[] = "d_";


   for (i=0; i<nc ; i++){
    s1 = con;
    s2 = string_IntToString(i);
    Connections[i]= string_Conc(s1,s2);  
    string_StringFree(s2);     
            }
```

EDIT

```
      char* string_Conc(const char* s1, const char* s2)
      { 
      char* dst;

    dst = memory_Malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    strcpy(dst, s1);
    return strcat(dst,s2);
      }
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything by looking at a probably corrupt stack trace. The real error could be anywhere, most likely a buffer overflow or something similar. It is hard to recommend anything except to look carefully at the code and to try commenting out various parts of it, checking if the error is still in place after that.

Comment: If you have access to GDB why dont you put some break points and try to debug. Was there a core generated?

Comment: Have you compiled your program with debugging symbols enabled, e.g. by using the `-g` GCC option? Your backtrace is not really helpful as it is, although it could probably just be corrupted.

Comment: @thkala: yes, i have used -g option while compiling.

Comment: What about `-O0`? Anything higher will mangle the executable beyond any recognition. BTW, we would be able to help more if you posted some of your code.

Comment: What you pasted isn't very informative. Can you post string_Conc() ?

Comment: @Tim i have posted the string_Conc()

Comment: I assume by your "with zero byte memory leak" comment that you have run the program under Valgrind and no problem was detected?

Comment: We also need more information on your OS and hardware platform, in order to provide more specific information...

Answer (score 7):

As commenters have pointed out, this sounds like a buffer overrun or some other event that leads to a corrupted heap, call stack, or similar.

You could try running your code through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it can often catch mistakes like those.

Answer (score 1):

Segfault at the end of the program could also be a sign of memory management which hasn't been fully designed. You might not have designed which object owns which object and in which order they will be deleted. For example there might be some singletons or similar that never get deleted and others that do, and some of them expect that others still exist when they really have been deleted, and then everything falls apart at the exit.

Answer (score 1):

The `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` symbol is filled-in by the dynamic linker at runtime. A corruption at that location points to a possible toolchain issue.

A few things to consider:

- Try installing the packages that contain the debugging symbols for the GCC libraries (`libgcc` and friends) and for the C library (`glibc` on most Linux distributions). This may allow the GDB backtrace to be more detailed.
- If you are creating a library, you need the `-fpic` or `-fPIC` options to create position-independent code. Without one of them you will see behaviour that can seem *very* weird.
- Verify that you are not mixing & matching resources from different toolchain versions.